# Serve unique assets to different different sub domain from a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

We are building a SAAS application (Similar like shopify) where we need to serve statics site (unique based on every sub domain) consists of HTML, CSS, Images and other asset based on sub domain from a rails app. As public folder serve the content based on main domain we kept it under vendor directory. Tried to create a controller only to serve that static html and all assets, found out it does not display the assets at all, display plain HTML only.

Please share your thoughts or any solution that you can think of. Thanks

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def reservation
  end
end

view/static_pages/home.html.haml
%h1 StaticPages#home
%p Find me in app/views/static_pages/home.html.haml

views/static_pages/about.html.haml
render file: Rails.public_path.join("templates","home.html"), layout: true



routes.rb
   get 'static_pages/home'
```